# How to write a generic moving average for a list of items?

Tags: c#

I have a class in c# declared as:

```
public class Item
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double XMovingAverage { get; set; }
    public double YMovingAverage { get; set; }
}
```

Assume now that I have a list of items like this:

```
List<Item> items = <ordered list of items>
```

Then I could calculate the moving average for X like this:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (var item in items)
{
    item.XMovingAverage = CalculateXMovingAverage(items, index, 100);
}

private double CalculateXMovingAverage(List<Item> items, int index, int N)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    int i = index;
    int n = 0;
    while ((n < N) & (i >= 0))
    {
        sum += items[i].X;
        n++;
        i--;
    }

    double movingAverage = sum / n;

    return movingAverage;
}
```

This works fine, but it's not very elegant, since if I want to calculate the moving average for Y, I need to copy / paste exactly the same code again for Y as I already wrote for X.

How could this be done more elegant to allow one to calculate the moving average for any numeric value for the items in a list?

Comment: I think what you want is a delegate.  Too many distractions around me to provide an example at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try something like this. You dont need generics as `X` and `Y` is both `double`. I wrote it without testing in IDE, but should work fine.

```
int index = 0;
foreach (var item in items)
{
    item.XMovingAverage = CalculateMovingAverage(items, index, 100, item => item.X);
    item.YMovingAverage = CalculateMovingAverage(items, index, 100, item => item.Y);
}

private double CalculateMovingAverage(List<Item> items, int index, int N, Func<Item, double> selector)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    int i = index;
    int n = 0;
    while ((n < N) & (i >= 0))
    {
        sum += selector(items[i]);
        n++;
        i--;
    }

    double movingAverage = sum / n;

    return movingAverage;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Func to get a function pointer to get the property to calculate the average for.

```
private double CalculateMovingAverage<TItem>(IList<TItem> items, int index, int N, Func<TItem, int> func)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    int i = index;
    int n = 0;
    while ((n < N) & (i >= 0))
    {
        sum += func(items[i]);
        n++;
        i--;
    }

    double movingAverage = sum / n;

    return movingAverage;
}
```

And can call it like:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (var item in items)
{
    item.XMovingAverage = CalculateMovingAverage(items, index, 100, (x) => x.X);
    item.XMovingAverage = CalculateMovingAverage(items, index, 100, (x) => x.Y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing this as a generic function like this (based on the answers above):

```
public static double SimpleMovingAverage<T>(List<T> items, int index, int N, Func<T, double> numberFunc)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    int i = index;
    int n = 0;
    while ((n < N) & (i >= 0))
    {
        sum += numberFunc(items[i]);
        n++;
        i--;
    }

    double movingAverage = sum / n;

    return movingAverage;
}
```

I also created a function for Exponential Moving Average:

```
public static double ExponentialMovingAverage<T>(List<T> items, int index, int N, Func<T, double> numberFunc)
{
    int n = Math.Min(index + 1, N); // May have to use smaller series in the beginning

    double k = 2.0 / (n + 1.0);

    double currentEMA = SimpleMovingAverage<T>(items, index, N, numberFunc); // Use Simple Moving Average as the starting point

    int start = index - n + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double previousEMA = currentEMA;
        double value = numberFunc(items[start + i]);
        currentEMA = (value * k) + previousEMA * (1.0 - k);
    }

    return currentEMA;
}
```

Now, I can use these in a re-usable library across different kind of lists and on any double value within the items.